# SQL Server : executing a trigger AFTER the data is committed. Is it possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I might be fighting a losing battle here, but after many attempts, I thought I should ask.

We have a 'use' table that data gets written to from various different sources and in different ways.

We have a procedure that looks at this table and based on that data calculates various metrics, inserting it into another table, this is run overnight.

I'd like to be able to keep this data table up-to-date as the use table changes, rather than just regenerate overnight.

I wrote a trigger for the use table that, based on the users being updated, ran the procedure just for those users and updated their data.

The problem, of course, is this data is calculated by looking at all records for that user in the use table and as the trigger fires during the insert/transaction, the calculation doesn't include the data being inserted.

I then thought I could change the trigger to insert the userids into another table and run a trigger on that table, so it does the calculations then, thinking it was another transaction. I was wrong.

Currently, the only working solution I have is to insert userids into this 2nd table and have a sql job running every 10 seconds waiting for userids to appear in the table and then running the sync proc from there, but it's not ideal as there are a lot of dbs this would need to run through, and it would be awkward to maintain.

Ideally I'd like to be able to run the trigger after the commit has taken place so all the records are available. I've looked at AFTER INSERT but even that runs before the commit, so I'm unsure as to what use it even is.

Anyone have any ideas, or am I trying to do something that is just not possible?

Really basic example of what I mean:

```
tblUse
userid, activityid
1, 300
1, 301
2, 300
3, 303
```

So userid 1 currently has 2 records in the table

userid 1 performs an activity and a record gets added.

So after the transaction has been committed, userid 1 will have 3 records in the table.

The problem I have is if I were to count the records at the point the trigger is run I'll still only get 2 as the 3rd hasn't committed yet.

I also can't just move the calculations into the trigger and union the INSERTED table data as it's a very big and complicated script that joins on multiple tables.

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Sounds like you're using an `INSTEAD OF` instead of an `AFTER` `TRIGGER`. A `AFTER` `TRIGGER` will see the *new* data in the table, as it triggers *after* the DML statement and is within the same transaction so has visibility.

Comment: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=04f9448ff0e38ea2a58eca211d602bbe) for proof.

Comment: @larnu if there was an `instead of` trigger the insert wouldn't happen in the base table unless the trigger code inserted it...?

Comment: Correct, @Stu . That doesn't mean that the OP *isn't* inserting it in the `TRIGGER`. They haven't given us the DDL after all. But my point remains, an `AFTER` trigger can definitely see the new data.

Comment: Also, to answer the question in the title: No, a `TRIGGER` cannot be fired *after* the transaction is committed. Anything that happens in the `TRIGGER` happens within the same transaction as the DML statement that caused it to fire. For an `AFTER` trigger, this means that the object it is a trigger on will appear to have had all the changes completed. For an `INSTEAD OF` none of them (because the `TRIGGER` is explicitly there to do something *instead of* what was sent via the DML statement), and the affected/new rows will only be available in the `inserted` and `deleted` pseudo tables.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I definitely haven't been using INSTEAD OF. Only FOR and AFTER have been tried.

Comment: There are only 2 types of trigger, `instead of` or `after`; `for` and `after` are synonymous

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the example. I can't explain it, but it's not working like that for me. The trigger execs AFTER/FOR INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, in which I run the procedure to do the calculations, and it calculates not including the records that have just been added (the insert that caused the trigger to fire). If I run it manually afterwards, I then get the correct figures

Comment: You need to supply a [mre] then, @DaveL , as what you're saying isn't how triggers work.

Comment: I'm confused: you say "as the trigger fires during the insert/transaction, the calculation doesn't include the data being inserted." this is simply not true, as `AFTER` triggers can see the data inserted. Please show your actual trigger code. I suspect an **Indexed View** may be the correct solution here, but it's hard to say without any code and table definitions, we really need to see those.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code itself is too massive to be able to post. I'm dealing with 15m record tables and about 20+ joins in the calculations. I've done some test cases and I do believe it is actually trying to update as you say but I'm thinking maybe the calculation is having trouble returning the correct data. This might be a non-issue after all. Very odd though as originally it wouldn't work with the proc in the trigger but running it in isolation after inserting records worked fine.

Comment: I've since done some tests and I can see data updating as the trigger runs, just not all of it so I think perhaps something else is going on. Thanks for the help guys, at least you've confirmed what I thought the trigger should be doing.. I'm guessing the problem is elsewhere down the line.